# In Pages Editor, how can I increase the 300 character limit for a single-line text field?

Tags: horizon, xm-cloud, sitecore-cloud

I noticed that the `single-line text field` when in the new Pages editor is **by default limited to 300** characters only.

How can I increase it?
[image]

Comment: you need to create custom field and customization code for single line text